# OpenSIPs Control Panel errors

Tags: kamailio, opensips, openser

I have setup OpenSIPs control panel and I can successfully complete basic functions like adding users. Problem is I keep getting this error when clicking on most features in the control panel.

MI command failed with code 406

Not sure how to fix, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using an 8.2.4 Control Panel with a 2.3 OpenSIPS.  Please make sure to bump your OpenSIPS version as well to 2.4, so it stays compatible with your current release of the CP.  Alternatively, you could downgrade the CP to 8.2.3.

PS: the error itself means that the CP is trying to issue a JSON-RPC call to the *httpd* webserver built into OpenSIPS via HTTP POST, with 2.3 and older versions of OpenSIPS only supporting GET, hence the 406 reply.

Comment: Currently using OpenSIPS Control Panel version 7.2.3 with OpenSIPs 2.4.6. Either way it sounds like a mis-match from what you're saying. I don't want to change my OpenSIPs version, I would rather try to match the control panel to the version of OpenSIPs I'm running. So, I am off to figure out which OpenSIPs control panel is compatible with my version of OpenSIPs to see if that's a fix. Thanks for your response.

Comment: That was it, mis-matched versions. I changed to 8.2.4 for the control panel and all is well now. Thank You